# Grouping items in a list Python

Tags: python

This code was written in `Scala`.

Is it possible to write it in Python using built-in functions?

Scala Code:

```
List(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9).grouped(4).toList.map { group =>
    println("begin")
        group.map { item =>
            println(item)
        }
    println("end")
}
```

Result:

```
begin
1
2
3
4
end
begin
5
6
7
8
end
begin
9
end
```

I tried, but didn't succeed.

Comment: Basically you're looking for [How do you split a list into evenly sized chunks in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks-in-python).